# Deserializing uniform arrays from JSON to real type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to parse JSON strings to:

```
private Dictionary<string, dynamic> dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
```

Where the values are restricted numeric arrays (all `int`s or `double`s (or even `dict`s but not mixed) and other `dict`s like that one (recursively).

I can use Newtonsoft's [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs) to parse the `dict`, but I'm getting arrays as `Object[]` instead of `int[]` or `double[,]`. I'm using my own `Serializer` which cast the `List<object>` the `ExpandoObjectConverter` create to `object[]`.

I do assume more about my information, so how can this be done?

Comment: So like this? https://gist.github.com/FurkanKambay/f0b2a73034895ac188a1a4733f5bb867

Comment: The `ExpandoObjectConverter` implementation looks like it's creating `List<object>`, not the `object[]` you say you're getting. Are you actually getting a different type, are you actually using another `ExpandoObjectConverter` class, or am I misreading what it does?

Comment: @FurkanKambay Exactly. Arrays can be multidimensional, and possible have `dict`s in them (again, all `dict`s without other types).

Comment: @hvd I'm using my own version which cast `List<object>` to `object[]` where all the rest is the same. sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: @galah92 If you've already got custom code to convert `List<object>` to `object[]`, modifying that to convert to either `int[]` or `double[]`, depending on which values you've got, seems trivial. If all values are of type `int`, convert to `int[]`. If all values are of type `double`, convert to `double[]`. Otherwise (which you say never happens), throw an exception to signal bad input. Is this the part you're having trouble with, or did this miss some important case?

Comment: Technically you're right. I'm having trouble with multidimensional arrays (because I need to parse them recursively in a way) and with the fact that I might be needed to add more types later (besides `int` and `double`), so I'm basically wandering if there's an elegant way of achieving this. Maybe a hack in `Json.Net` I missed that could help. Also, how do I check if they're all of the same type efficiently?

Comment: This should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/4187549

Comment: @FurkanKambay Thanks, but it looks like the custom `Converter` is useless there. Just parsing it to `JToken` would be enough. Besides that, in my case I do not have a custom class I can parse into (unlike the example), and I cannot define one as one cannot restrict the `dynamic` values (to my knowledge).